# I am drawing a cycle in TikZ, need to add integer labels on the outside of each node

Tags: tikz-styles, tikz-trees, graphs

Here is what I have so far:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzstyle{every node}=[draw, circle, fill=black, inner sep=0pt, 
minimum size=5pt]
\tikzstyle{every path}=[line width=.75 pt]
\foreach \s in {1,...,5}
{\node at ({72 * (\s - 1)+90}:1.25) {};
\draw ({72 * (\s - 1)+90}:1.25) arc ({72 * (\s - 1)+90}:{72 * 
(\s)+90}:1.25);}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Any suggestions is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very short code (following the AndréC's idea):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \foreach \r in {1,2,...,5}{
        \draw[line width=.75pt] circle(1.25);
        \fill  (72*\r+18:1.25) circle(5pt);
        \node at (72*\r+18:1.6) {\r};
    }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: Good, but it is better to take the `circle` out of the `foreach,` otherwise, you construct and trace this circle 5 times!

Comment: @AndréC You are right!

Answer (score 4):

Instead of tracing the circle in pieces, I traced it all at once. To place the labels, I placed them on a larger diameter circle that is not constructed.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzstyle{every node}=[draw, circle, fill=black, inner sep=0pt, 
minimum size=5pt]
\tikzstyle{every path}=[line width=.75 pt]
%draw the circle
\draw (0,0) circle (1.25cm);
\foreach \s in {1,...,5}
{% positionning node
\node at ({72 * (\s - 1)+90}:1.25) {};
%\draw ({72 * (\s - 1)+90}:1.25) arc ({72 * (\s - 1)+90}:{72 * 
%(\s)+90}:1.25);
%positioning label
\node[fill=none,draw=none]at({72 * (\s - 1)+90}:1.5){$\s$};
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

A variant with essentially just one line of Ti*k*Z:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[line width=.75pt] (18:1.25) arc[start angle=18, end angle=378, radius=1.25]
        foreach \r in {1,2,...,5} {
            node[pos={1/5*\r}, circle, fill, inner sep=2.5pt, label={[anchor=270+(72*(\r-1))]90+(72*(\r-1)):\r}] {}
        };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

And a `l3draw` version:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{l3draw}

\begin{document}
    \ExplSyntaxOn
    
    \draw_begin:
    \draw_linewidth:n { .75pt }
    \draw_path_circle:nn { 0cm , 0cm } { 1.25cm }
    \draw_path_use_clear:n { stroke }
    
    \int_set:Nn \l_tmpa_int { 1 }
    \int_step_inline:nn { 5 } {
        \draw_path_circle:nn { \draw_point_polar:nn { 1.25cm } { 18 + 72 * #1 } } { 2.5pt }
        \draw_path_use_clear:n { fill }
        \hcoffin_set:Nn \l_tmpa_coffin { #1 }
        \draw_coffin_use:Nnnn \l_tmpa_coffin { hc } { vc } { \draw_point_polar:nn { 1.65cm } { 18 + 72 * #1 } }
    }
    \draw_end:
    
    \ExplSyntaxOff
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You are ready to write a little tutorial about `l3draw`... :-) More seriously, is there a technical advantage to using `l3draw`?

Comment: @projetmbc Well, Ti*k*Z is a huge tool that loads a lot of things you might not really need when drawing relatively simple things (such as this circle). Using `l3draw` will therefore make compilations quicker, I'd say. But of course, there are also drawbacks: It is more clumsy in terms of coding because it is not a front-end package. For example, it does not come with a key-based styling mechanism. But it also has some other benefits: For example, it uses tuples as coordinates which can make calculations very simple.